# finding the vorticity

Tags: vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to solve this problem
[image]

[image]

however i am struggling to compute this, as i get the vorticity to be f(r)/r but this isn't right

any hints on how to do this would be great

Comment: To do this, you have to either know the formula for curl in polar coordinates or convert the vector into rectangular coordinates.  Which is your preference?

Comment: i have a formula for the curl in polar coordinates, so would prefer to use that

Comment: If you have that formula, what is the difficulty with applying it?  You should have a derivative of $f$, but you don't have that in the formula.

Comment: i just don't seem to be getting to the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't use the product rule here.  The relevant term in the formula for curl is
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial (rf)}{\partial r}$$
which yields
$$\frac{f}{r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$$
according to the product rule.  It is easy to show that this vanishes for the given $f$.